Poem about a cherry pie being saved, betrayed, and eaten
I once read (in a collection/anthology of children's literature?) a poem about a cherry pie. The title might have been just "Cherry Pie", but it wasn't this or this or this or this (you can see a web search has been no help). It was quite short, probably fitting on one page when printed, but several verses rather than just one.
There was a narrative to it: the protagonist is a human (girl?) who meets a talking (sentient?) cherry pie somewhere in a road. The cherry pie is lost, so the human takes it home and takes care of it, but ends up eating it. The actual eating is implied rather than explicitly stated, with the focus being on the forlorn reaction of the pie as it disappears piece by piece. There may or may not have been illustrations, possibly a drawing of the cherry pie (with limbs and a face?) on the road.
I read it in English, which I think was the original language, at a public library in England, somewhere in the mid-2000s. The author might have been someone famous, if the anthology I had was a collection of short pieces by well-known authors.
